# Can't set traits for jenkins git sum plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to add the `jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait` trait to our seed job. But I did not get it to run.

Theoretically this should work, but it doesn't. How can I set these properties?

```
multibranchPipelineJob(projectNsPath) {
    displayName(projectId)

    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            source {
                git {
                    remote(projectUrl)

                    configure { node ->
                        node / traits {
                            'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait'()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            strategy {
                defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
                    props {
                        noTriggerBranchProperty()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    orphanedItemStrategy {
        discardOldItems {
            numToKeep(20)
        }
    }
}
```

1) From [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/The-Configure-Block.md) the configure block should select the node where its defined, so

```
git {
    configure { node ->
        ...
    }
}
```

`node` must be the `<source plugin="git@3.8.0" class="jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource">` element, but it is the root element.

2) If I use the complete path `node / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait'()` it creates a second `source` node.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `configure` method in the `git` context below `branchSource`, it's only available for the `git` context below `scm`. Use the API viewer to lookup availability of methods.

But you can use a top-level configure block to generate the trait:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
  branchSources {
    branchSource {
      source {
        git {
          remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
        }
      }
      strategy {
        defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
          props {
            noTriggerBranchProperty()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  configure { node ->
    node / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits {
      'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait'()
    }
  }
}
```